# What does `new auto` do?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-allocation, type-deduction

What does it mean when I use `new auto`? Consider the expression:

```
new auto(5)
```

What is the type of the dynamically allocated object? What is the type of the pointer it returns?

Comment: I couldn't find this question anywhere, so I figured I'd ask it.

Comment: Gcc says it's an [`int`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/n2hHZ$0).

Comment: C++11 5.3.4/2, it's `int`.

Comment: Please, don't do this in your public commits, I have enough weird C++ code on my hands already  :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this context, `auto(5)` resolves to `int(5)`.

You are allocating a new `int` from the heap, initialized to `5`.

*(So, it's returning an `int *`)*

Quoting Andy Prowl's resourceful answer, with permission:

Per Paragraph 5.3.4/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> If the `auto` type-specifier appears in the *type-specifier-seq* of a *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a *new-expression*, the
>   *new-expression* shall contain a *new-initializer* of the form
>
> ```
> ( assignment-expression )
> ```
>
> The allocated type is deduced from the new-initializer as follows: Let `e` be the *assignment-expression* in
>   the *new-initializer* and T be the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of the *new-expression*, then the allocated type is the type
>   deduced for the variable `x` in the invented declaration (7.1.6.4):
>
> ```
> T x(e);
> ```
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> new auto(1); // allocated type is int
> auto x = new auto(’a’); // allocated type is char, x is of type char*
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Comment: Throw in the standard quote that says why and I'll accept. :P

Comment: @sftrabbit Thanks, but I'd only be stealing Andy Prowl's work at this point.

Comment: @Drew everyone will benefit from your *"stealing"*.

Comment: @ulidtko Except Andy and/or Xeo. I think Drew has morals!

Comment: Although I haven't copied it, I realize now that the relevant standard reference appeared in the comments before I posted my answer. So I think it is technically fair to "steal" it ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl I like your style, Dude.

Answer (score 14):

Per Paragraph 5.3.4/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> If the `auto` type-specifier appears in the *type-specifier-seq* of a *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a *new-expression*, the
>   *new-expression* shall contain a *new-initializer* of the form
>
> ```
> ( assignment-expression )
> ```
>
> The allocated type is deduced from the new-initializer as follows: Let `e` be the *assignment-expression* in
>   the *new-initializer* and T be the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of the *new-expression*, then the allocated type is the type
>   deduced for the variable `x` in the invented declaration (7.1.6.4):
>
> ```
> T x(e);
> ```
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> new auto(1); // allocated type is int
> auto x = new auto(’a’); // allocated type is char, x is of type char*
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Therefore, the type of the allocated object is identical to the deduced type of the invented declaration:

```
auto x(5)
```

Which is `int`.

Comment: You beat me to finding the reference, fair and square.  +1  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann: But you gave the correct answer first, well done ;)

Comment: Sanity-checking my answer on the web was *worthless* when I searched for "new auto"...

Comment: It is not worthless. Car dealers affiliation commission. This is the primary source of revenue for the ISO-C++