# placement new for lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have an interesting problem with C++ lambdas. The use case is a performance-critical thread that constructs a lambda with non-empty closure which is then passed to a different thread so it can be "worked" on.

The overall idea works but my lambda closure object gets copied one extra time and compiler (currently g++ 5.4.0) is not able to optimize away this copy including with copy elision. I also tried clang with similar outcome.

Ideally I would like to use a placement new when creating lambda objects directly in the durable memory instead of first creating object on stack for example:

```
auto l = new (buf) [a,b,c](){}
```

The error is something like:

```
lambda_ctor.cpp:39:19: error: expected type-specifier before '[' token
    auto al = (buf) new [a,b,c](){};
```

I was thinking maybe if I had a type in hand instead of actual lambda expression compiler should accept it but trying to lift type of closure without evaluating it runs into another problem:

```
using T = decltype([a,b,c](){});
```

with this error:

```
lambda_ctor.cpp:41:24: error: lambda-expression in unevaluated context
    using T = decltype([a,b,c](){});
```

I can't seem to find a way around this, there are a number of ideas on how to keep lambda from disintegrating on scope exit but every solution seems to involve copying/moving the closure object once it has been created (aka extra copy). This is a little strange because normally we have full control over how a user-defined functor is created and passed around and similar rules should apply to closures.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924996/c11-lambda-with-dynamic-storage-duration

Comment: Why not make a callable struct (functor)?

Comment: use `std::function` as lambda container

Comment: The original poster is concerned about an extra copy of the lambda, so it seems like the possible memory allocation in std::function would be even more unacceptable.

Answer (score 3):

`auto` is your friend.

```
auto l = new (buf) auto([a,b,c](){});
```

Any copy of the closure object should be elidable.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for, no copy is created and closure members are initialized in place, thank you very much!

Comment: When was this added?  14 or 17?  Wait a sec, [11?!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)  [yep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935080/what-does-new-auto-do), I had no clue.

Comment: @Yakk Actually, I'm fairly sure 11.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
auto l = new (buf) auto([a, b, c]{});
```

But you have to know that `buf` has enough space to hold the lambda. In order to find the size of the actual lambda you would need to do something like

```
auto l = [a, b, c]{};
auto size = sizeof(l);
```

But now you've created the lambda on the stack, which you didn't want to do. But now you know how big the buffer has to be, and can do

```
auto buf = new char[size];
auto lptr = new (buf) auto(std::move(l));
```

And the lambda will be moved into the buffer.

Eventually, though, you will need to destruct the lambda and free the buffer. The lambda can be easily destructed with a template function.

```
template<typename Lambda>
void destruct(Lambda* l)
{
    l->~Lambda();
}
```

Comment: Here is a way to find out size of capture by using un-evaluated branch: template <typename T> T* get_ptr(T t) { return nullptr; }    auto * l = false ? get_ptr(lambda goes here) : nullptr;   enum { lambda_size = sizeof(*l); }

Comment: @rtz That lambda does not have to be the same size as a lambda on the very next line with the same body...